# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)}{2n-1}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried solving this but couldn't. I tried a sorta hacky approach and that was substituting $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and made my way to a comparison which resulted in $\frac{\sin(u)}{\frac{2}{u^2}-1} \leq \frac{1}{u^2}$ but then I noticed that I didn't changed my summation bounds since it was from $n=1$ to $n \to \infty$ and I now think I should have changed it to be suitable for $u$ but I guessed it'd be wrong and bizzare so I didn't even attempt it. I know it's hacky and this wasn't really taught by my professors or anything, I was just giving it a go. What's the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the sum of the infinite series, or do you just want to know if it converges/diverges?

Comment: I want to know if it's convergent or divergent AND know whether or not that u-substitution hack is valid.

Comment: @EyadH. We should have $$\frac{\sin(u)}{\frac{2}{u^2}-1} \leq \frac{u}{\frac{2}{u^2}-1}= \frac{u^3}{2-u^2}\sim \frac12 u^3=\frac{1}{2n\sqrt n}$$ which is exactly the same result we can obtain manipulating the original expression.

Comment: @Decaf-Math I had the same doubt initially but it is clear from the context that the asker was looking for convergence/divergence.

Comment: @gimusi so the u-substitution isn't invalid because of the (I think) changed bounds?

Comment: @EyadH. It is valid but at the end we need to reconvert to $n$. I think sincerly that it is not necessary, you can handle the original expression in a easy way, we don't need substitution. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that for $n$ large

$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n }\right)}{2n-1} \sim\frac{1}{2n\sqrt n}$$ then refer to limit comparison test.

Comment: So is my approach absolutely wrong or is the whole substitution thing viable? Either in this problem or in other problems?

Comment: @EyadH. By comparison test we can use of course that $\sin x <x$ for $x>0$ and then $$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)})}{2n-1}\le \frac{1}{(2n-1)\sqrt n}\le \frac{1}{2n\sqrt n}$$ and conclude in the same way.

Comment: @EyadH. The advantage by LCT is that we don't need to worry about inequalities which are more elegent but also much more subtle to handle or to remember!

Comment: @EyadH. I don't understand that step $\frac{sin(u)}{\frac{2}{u^2}-1} \leq \frac{1}{u^2}$ I think that it is better to act directly with the original expression letting $n \to \infty$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: I thought that since $-1 \leq sin(u) \leq 1$ and $\frac{2}{u^2}-1 \leq \frac{1}{u^2}$ then it implied $\frac{sin(u)}{\frac{2}{u^2}-1} \leq \frac{1}{u^2}$ too. I don't know, I was pretty desperate to be honest and I was trying to hack myself through that ugly series and that seemed to make it easier and made sense.

Comment: @EyadH. Opsss...As I said inequalitie are subtle, I did wrong here in the comment, can you see why? We should use that eventually $$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)})}{2n-1}\le \frac{1}{(2n-1)\sqrt n}\le \frac{1}{n\sqrt {n}}$$